# PySpark S3 file read performance consideration

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am new bee to pyspark.
Just wanted to understand how large files I should write into S3 so that Spark can read those files and process.

I have around 400 to 500GB of total data, I need to first upload them to S3 using some tool.
Just trying to understand how big each file should be in S3 so that Spark can read and process efficiently.
And how spark will distribute the S3 files data to multiple executors?

Any god reading link?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Try 64-128MB, though it depends on the format.
- Spark treats S3 data as independent of location, so doesn't use locality in its placement decisions -just whichever workers have capacity for extra work